# Data is still downloading from firebase even using firebase offline capabilities

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase offline capabilities to fetch data from cache once it load all data in local disk even if my internet is on.I successfully managed to do it but when ever I read data in my app, my firebase data download size increases. I am confused: when I get data from local cache, my data download size increases every time I am reading data in my app. If anyone knows please help me out.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet to clarify your problem?

Comment: I just used the code below FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

Comment: I read alots of article and documentations and summarized that by using this snippet code will store data in local disk and next time it will only fetch data from cache not from server if data is not changed.Please correct me if I am wrong in summarising all.

Answer (score 1):

Even when the data is already in the cache, the Firebase client will connect to the server and check if the cached data is up to date. This check is typically significantly smaller than downloading the actual data, but you'll still be charged for the bandwidth it consumes.

If you want to work completely offline, and don't want the client to check with the server at all, you can [tell the Firebase client to `goOffline`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#goOffline()) when the app starts.

Comment: Okay i understood but if I tell the client to go offline how would I check for the data updated in firebase

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: If you want to check if the data is updated, you should not tell the client to go offline. But in that case you will be charged for the bandiwdth that the check takes.